# Relations between $M_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ and $M_k(\Gamma_0(L,M))$, and Eisenstein Series.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Consider the following congruence subgroups
$$\Gamma_0(N):=\Big\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\in\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\; \Big| \; c\equiv0\text{ (mod }N)\Big\}$$
and
$$\Gamma_0(L,M):=\Big\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\in\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\; \Big| \; c\equiv0\text{ (mod }L)\;\text{ and } 
  \;b\equiv0\text{ (mod }M) \Big\}.$$
Is there some sort of relationship between modular forms over these groups? Say, for example, if $N=LM$ or $N=\text{lcm}(N,M)$?

I am asking this because I was reading Miyake's book (titled "Modular Forms"), at chapter 7, for two characters $\chi$ and $\psi$ of modulus $L$ and $M$, he defines the Eisenstein Series $E_k(z,s,\chi,\psi)$. He then proves (for $s=0$ and under some conditions), that they are modular over $\Gamma_0(L,M)$ with nebentypus $\chi\bar{\psi}$.

However, everywhere else that I see these Eisensteins series they are understood as being modular over $\Gamma_0(LM)$. For example https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/eisenstein.html (see the comments after equation (4)).

I am confused. Are these the same series, or do they require some slight modification to be modular over $\Gamma_0(LM)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that there is a convenient relationship between $\Gamma_0(L, M)$ and $\Gamma_0(N)$. But there is a relationship between the Eisenstein series defined on them. The Eisenstein series in Stein and the Eisenstein series in Miyake aren't quite the same Eisenstein series.

Stein's Eisenstein series appears earlier in Miyake's book. It's the one described in Theorem 4.7.1 (pg 177) of Miyake, which is shown to be modular on $\Gamma_0(LM)$, where $L$ and $M$ are the conductors of the Dirichlet characters (where I use the notation from chapter 7 and your question, which differs from the notation in the book in chapter 4).

Below Theorem 7.1.3 of Miyake, in equation 7.1.13 (pg 271), Miyake states that one gets the Stein-type Eisenstein series via
$$ E_k(Mz; \chi, \psi) = c E_{\mathrm{Stein}}(z; \chi, \overline{\psi}) $$
for a constant $c = c(k, \psi, M)$. Here, $E_{\mathrm{Stein}}$ is my notation for the Stein-type Eisenstein series.

Thus the conversion is to consider $E_k(Mz; \chi, \psi)$, which is modular on $\Gamma_0(LM)$. Stein translates results from Miyake through this identity for his book.

### Additional note: a typo in Stein

There is a typo that make this comparison more confusing. Equation 4 in https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/eisenstein.html (or equivalently equation 5.3.1 in the book version), $\psi(n)$ should be replaced by $\overline{\psi}(n)$. And in Theorem 5.9, the condition should either read
$\chi = \varepsilon \psi$ or $\chi \overline{\psi} = \varepsilon$.

In fact, this was the source of a problem in sagemath for a bit. [Here is the source of that trac ticket](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/4062)

Comment: Thank you so much for this superb answer! I was genuinely confused! So, it was that sneaky multiplication by $M$ that did the trick. One question though, for $k=1$, let us say $f_1(z;\chi,\psi)$ are the Eisenstein series from Miyake's Theorem 4.7.1, which satisfy something like $L(1,f_1(z;\chi,\psi))=L(1,\chi)L(1,\psi)$, but require $\chi$ and $\psi$ to be primitive. Do you know if the more general definition of Eisenstein series from chapter 7 (that do not require $\chi$ and $\psi$ primitive), can be used to generalize such equation without requiring primitivity?

Comment: Let us say $\chi'$ and $\psi'$ are the primitive character attached to $\chi$ and $\psi$. On the right hand side of $L(1,f_{1}(z;\chi',\psi'))=L(1,\chi')L(1,\psi')$, the change from primitive to non-primitive would simply remove some Euler factors. But on the left hand side, things look complicated. It is unclear to me if the more general Eiseinstein series I get from converting from chapter 7 work. Maybe after some further modifications?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure how imprimitivity affects the proofs without going through them again myself. [This paper of Matt Young](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03624) might be a useful reference. It includes various explicit computations that aren't written down in many places.

Comment: By the way, there *is* a convenient relation between $\Gamma_0(L,M)$ and $\Gamma_0(N)$: for any $q \mid M$, $\begin{pmatrix} q^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \Gamma_0(L,M) \begin{pmatrix} q & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \Gamma_0(qL,\frac{M}{q})$. In particular, $\begin{pmatrix} M^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \Gamma_0(L,M) \begin{pmatrix} M & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \Gamma_0(LM)$.

Comment: So if $f(z)$ is a modular form for $\Gamma_0(L,M)$, then $f(qz)$ is a modular form for $\Gamma_0(qL,\frac{M}{q})$; in particular, $f(Mz)$ is a modular form for $\Gamma_0(LM)$.